# Interrupting CSS animation causes weird transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been experimenting with creating "cards" that expand when you click them to the full viewport of the window. It has been going well apart from when you interrupt the animation before it has finished, it causes some graphical glitches. I am using CSS transitions instead of Javascript animations (I am just using JQuery for prototyping the required class change) and implementation in CSS only also has this issue. Please use the JSFiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/ny85ebgu/1/ as it seems the code doesn't work properly on StackOverflow.

```js
$(window).on("click", ".small", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).addClass("big"); }, 1 );
});

$(window).on("click", ".big", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).removeClass("big"); }, 1 );
});
```

```css
div.small {
    background: #f00;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 6;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.smaller {
    background: black;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 2rem;
    left: calc(((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3) + 4rem);
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.smallest {
    background: blue;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 2rem;
    left: calc((((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3) * 2) + 6rem);
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.even-smaller {
    background: green;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc(((100% - 6rem) / 2));
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 3;
    top: calc(((100% - 6rem) / 2) + 4rem);
    left: 2rem;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.really-small {
    background: pink;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 2;
    top: calc(((100% - 6rem) / 2) + 4rem);
    left: calc((((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3) * 1) + 4rem);
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.amazingly-small {
    background: orange;
    width: calc((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100% - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
    top: calc(((100% - 6rem) / 2) + 4rem);
    left: calc((((100% - 4rem - 4rem) / 3) * 2) + 6rem);
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.big {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small smaller"></div>
<div class="small smallest"></div>
<div class="small even-smaller"></div>
<div class="small really-small"></div>
<div class="small amazingly-small"></div>
```

You will notice that the when interacting with the top row it seems to animate from the left and top when you interrupt it back to its normal position, while the bottom row excluding the leftmost "card" just snaps back. Also note, that I have tried without calc() and that doesn't help.

Preferably I want to animation to run in reverse.

EDIT: It seems that this is an issue in Safari. Works fine in Chrome and other Chromium browsers. Not sure about Firefox though.

Comment: I don't see this issue (Firefox, Win10). Which browser on which platform does this issue occur?

Comment: Sorry, see edit. Seems to be an issue on Safari (I know), good to know that it works in Firefox. I need this to work in Safari though so do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Safari on MacOS, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Which MacOS? Which Safari Version?

Comment: 10.14.6 (why is that relevant?) and Safari version 12.1.2 (the latest public version).

Comment: The version is relevant because often the different version have different behaviours

Comment: Ok. So different macOS versions with the same Safari version can have different behaviors? Makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems indeed to be a Safari bug, triggered by the use of relative units.
Apparently they fail to come back from the current state to a percentage based value.

You will thus need to use absolute units to workaround that issue.
In your case, you can simply replace all the initial `width:[..]%[..]` with `width:[..]vw[..]` and all the `height` with `vh`.

```js
$(window).on("click", ".small", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).addClass("big"); }, 1 );
});

$(window).on("click", ".big", function() {
    me = this;
    setTimeout( function() { $(me).removeClass("big"); }, 1 );
});
```

```css
div.small {
    background: #f00;
    width: calc((100vw - 4rem - 4rem) / 3);
    height: calc((100vh - 6rem) / 2);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    z-index: 6;
    top: 2rem;
    left: 2rem;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div.big {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
<div class="small"></div>
```

Comment: Annoying, but has a simple fix. Thanks.