# How to fix css transition bug in Safari?

Tags: css, transition, translate

I need to make a slider like this https://codepen.io/dobladov/pen/kXAXJx. But it doesn't work properly in Safari. It twitches every time when I clicked on "next" or "prev" button. Could anyone help me to fix the bug or give me a link to another slider that works on Safari.

```
div
    position: absolute
    transition: transform 1s, left 1s, opacity 1s, z-index 0s
    opacity: 1

    img
      width: 400px
      transition: width 1s

    &.hideLeft
      left: 0%
      opacity: 0
      transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%)

      img
        width: 200px

    &.hideRight
      left: 100%
      opacity: 0
      transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%)
      img
        width: 200px

    &.prev
      z-index: 5
      left: 30%
      transform: translateY(50px) translateX(-50%)

      img
        width: 300px

    &.prevLeftSecond
      z-index: 4
      left: 15%
      transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%)
      opacity: .7

      img
        width: 200px

    &.selected
      z-index: 10
      left: 50%
      transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-50%)

    &.next
      z-index: 5
      left: 70%
      transform: translateY(50px) translateX(-50%)

      img
        width: 300px

    &.nextRightSecond
      z-index: 4
      left: 85%
      transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%)
      opacity: .7

      img
        width: 200px
```

I tried to use `translate3D(50%, 50%, 0)` instead of `translateY(50%) translateX(-50%)`.

Comment: Looks like the same bug [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669912/interrupting-css-animation-causes-weird-transformation/57670455#57670455), however, in your case it might be harder to replace these relative values with absolute ones...

Comment: Thank you! Your link was helpful!